# overwrite the web view error from assets html page in android

Tags: android, webview

I am showing a url on web view,now i want to handle the server side webview error from overwriting the manually define html page from assets folder.
i am using the below code but webview showing the error from server side.

This is my fragment class-

```
public class homefragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
WebView homewebview;

String url="developer.android.com";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepage_frag, container, false);
    homewebview=(WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webview1);




        homewebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        homewebview.canGoBack();

        homewebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

            }
        });
        homewebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                // Handle the error
                if (errorCode == 404 || errorCode == 302 || errorCode == 502 || errorCode == 401 || errorCode == 400 || errorCode == 403 || errorCode == 500 || errorCode == 503 || errorCode == 505) {

                    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/networkerror.html");

                    return;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        homewebview.loadUrl(webstring);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

onReceivedError() is not called for HTTP error, it is called when non HTTP error happened such malformed URL or timeout. onReceivedHttpError() I believe is called when HTTP error occurred. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Comment: Please give me the solution.I am stuck with this for a long time..I have no more Idea about web view.